# FFT of complex envelope

Tags: fft, analytic-signal

I have I and Q samples of a time domain signal, sampled at a rate T, both of length L.

I create the complex envelope, `C = sampleI+j*sampleQ`.

Then take the FFT of C based on Matlab's FFT help algorithm:

```
Fs=1/T;
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L)
Y = fft(C,NFFT)/L
fvar = (0:NFFT/2)*(Fs/NFFT)
plot(fvar,2*abs(Y))
```

The frequency content of the complex envelope should only contain positive frequencies but the FFT returns results symmetric in frequency so is there anything I need to do to C or to Y to interpret the results properly?  Do I just throw away the upper half of the frequency components in the FFT result?

Comment: Just checking: in the code above you only plot positive frequencies, right? Could you post a link to a plot of the spectrum (including all frequencies from 0 to Fs)?

Comment: How/where did you get the I and Q samples?  Are they the captured samples from an actual signal?  Why do you think that they should only have positive frequencies?